# Nothing printing in a vowelgram program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was creating a vowelgram program that checks for a string to contain all the vowels. The vowels should also occur only once.
The program I created is as follows

```
n=input()
d=0
c=0
j=0
for i in range(0,len(n)):
    if(n[i]=="a" or n[i]=="e" or n[i]=="i" or n[i]=="o" or n[i]=="u"):
        c=c+1
        for j in range(i+1,len(n)):
            if(n[i]==n[j]):
                d=d+1
if(c==5):
    if(d==0):
        print("The number is a vowelgram")
else:
    print("The number isnt a vowelgram")
```

Unfortunately the program is printing nothing. I cannot seem to find the error in the code. Help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use `all` to check if all of vowels are in the string and are exactly once:

```
n = input('Enter string: ')
n = n.lower()

if all(x in n and n.count(x) == 1 for x in {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}):
    print('It is a vowelgram.')
else:
    print('It is not a vowelgram.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use (Counter)[https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter] class to count letters. Then check if every vowel count `countdict['a']<=1` is lower or equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not printing anything, for some input, you must be ending up in the *missing* `else` branch of the inner `if`:

```
if(c==5):
    if(d==0):
        print("The number is a vowelgram")
    # c==5, but d!=0
    # here , you will get no output!
else:  # this else applies only to the outer if: c!=5
    print("The number isnt a vowelgram")
```

You can remedy that, e.g. by using the following construct covering all (*other*) cases:

```
if c==5 and d==0:
    print("The number is a vowelgram")
else:
    print("The number isnt a vowelgram")
```

Generally however, your nested loops are not optimal performance-wise. You could use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to obtain a result in linear time:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(x for x in n if x in 'aeiou')
if len(c) == 5 and all(v==1 for v in c.values()):
    print('vowelgram')
else:
    print('not vowelgram')
```